# Assign a unique count to each row in the resulting table of a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's assume we have a simple database that has the following schema: **Article(Id, Body, AuthorId)** and **Author(Id, Name)**. Suppose that we want to develop a page where each author will be able to view his own posts only. There is only one requirement:

- When the author wants to see his posts, the SQL query should allow him to see a counter for each item, starting at 1.

**Example**
Here's a simple set up:
(1,"Hi",1), (2,"there",1), (3,"test",2), (4,"foo",1).

By executing some sort of SQL statement: `select count, body where authorid=1; 
we want to get:
(1,"Hi",1), (2,"there",1), (3,"foo",1).

**Question**
As you can see, the suggested statement wont work because **count** does not make sense yet. My question is, is there any way to assign a local count for each item  to produce the result above?

Comment: If we're talking about a web page, the typical solution would be to output the items as an [ordered list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol). This handles the display entirely in the presentation layer and lets you change the style of the list later in CSS, without changing your database or HTML code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` in your `SELECT`

`SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AuthorID), Body, AuthorID FROM Article;`

[Row Number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: @GordonLinoff - You're right and I will update; however, instead of a non-constructive comments like this wouldn't it have been better if you had provided an edit or your own answer?